# Maven is connecting then immediately discarding session

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am trying to figure out why Maven is refusing to download artifacts from our local Sonatype Nexus server. (Everything is on an air-gapped network, so please forgive any typos as I transcribe the details.) Also, I'm just the sysadmin trying to make this work; Maven is very new to me.

**Server**: Sonatype Nexus 3.40.1, using an Apache httpd/2.4.6 mod_ssl proxy. The certificate is issued by a FreeIPA/IdM server that all of the relevant systems are bound to; the client system recognizes the server certificate.

**Maven/Java**: Maven 3.5.0, Java 1.8.0_332

All systems involved are RHEL 7.9.

**What I'm Running**:

- This is a command that one of my developers gave me to test the Nexus server and is failing:
  `mvn -DgroupId=commons-io -DartifactId=commons-io -Dversion1.4 dependency:get --debug -Djavax.net.debug=all >& debug`

In the debug file, after Maven goes through a lengthy handshake process with the server and seems very happy, then it goes to start downloading artifacts and does this multiple times:

> [DEBUG] Secure connection established
> [DEBUG]  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
> [DEBUG]  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> [DEBUG]  peer principal: CN=repo.{my_domain}, O={MY_DOMAIN}
> [DEBUG] http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
> [DEBUG] Connection discarded
> [DEBUG] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}-> https://repo.{my_domain}:9000][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 40]
> [DEBUG] Writing tracking file ...
> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for ...

The only thing that I've been able to do to get Maven to work with this server is to disable https, but that's not really a viable solution in our environment.

I am able to directly download an artifact from the Nexus server with Firefox and curl without a problem.

Comment: Why using such an old Maven version?

Comment: It's what Red Hat ships in their Software Collections package. I just looked at Maven 3.6 is available in the SCL and I'll give that a try when I get a minute today.

Comment: The problem with such things is that the version 3.6.0 is of 2018 ... from my point of view much too old... https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html use the most recent  versions... Also you need to activate TLSv1.3 (`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.3`) See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @khmarbaise Agree with you 100% on using such an ancient version. I'd like to use a newer version, but I can only use what Red Hat supplies for "reasons."

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two things were going on here:

- First, we had to upgrade to Maven 3.6.x, which was able to successfully negotiate a TLS connection to the web server. (Yes, Maven 3.6 is ancient, but I can only use what Red Hat provides, for reasons.)
- Second, Sonatype documents the use of the following directive when using Apache as a reverse proxy for Nexus: RequestHeader: set X-Forward-Proto "https". Which works great if you have Apache listing on 443/tcp, which we don't (again, for reasons).

So, upgrading Maven and removing the http header seems to have fixed the problem.